# How to solve "Index was outisde the bound of the array" error?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, indexing

Hello I am using this code to get the data I need from 5 different tables on a MySQL database.

```
private void goDateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportList.Items.Clear();
            var db = new DBConnect();
            MySqlCommand cmd = null;
            MySqlDataReader dr = null;
            double totalsales = 0;
            try
            {
                if (db.OpenConnection() == true)
                {

                    string cmdstr = "SELECT ol.*, o.*, m.* "+
                                    "FROM orderlist ol "+
                                    "INNER JOIN orderdb o ON ol.order_ID = o.order_ID "+
                                    "INNER JOIN menudb m ON ol.menu_ID = m.menu_ID "+
                                    "INNER JOIN recipelist r ON r.menu_ID = m.menu_ID "+
                                    "INNER JOIN "+
                                    "( SELECT stock_ID, SUM(stock_pricePerPiece) menu_cost "+
                                        "FROM stocksdb "+
                                        "GROUP BY stock_ID )"+
                                    "s ON r.stock_ID = s.stock_ID "+
                                    "WHERE o.order_date >= #" + fromDate.Value.Date + "# AND " +
                                        "o.order_date <= #" + toDate.Value.Date + "#";
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, db.mycon);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    string[] info = new string[20];
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        info[1] = (dr["order_ID"].ToString());
                        info[2] = (dr["order_date"].ToString());
                        info[3] = (dr["menu_name"].ToString());
                        info[4] = (dr["menu_cost"].ToString());
                        info[5] = (dr["menu_price"].ToString());
                        info[6] = (Convert.ToDouble(info[5]) - Convert.ToDouble(info[4])).ToString("#0.00");
                        this.reportList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4], info[5], info[6] }));

                        totalsales += Convert.ToDouble(info[6]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (dr != null)
                {
                    dr.Close();
                }
                db.CloseConnnection();
            }
            totalSalesTxtBox.Text = totalsales.ToString("#0.00");
            MessageBox.Show("SALES REPORT FINISHED!");
        }
```

I don't really know what I did wrong especially in the sql string where the last `INNER JOIN` is supposed to add up all the `stock_pricePerPiece` from the `stocksdb` table wherein the stocks are used on the same menu hence having the same `menu_ID` in the `recipedb` table.

I am getting the error on `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: Can you debug and tell us which line you are getting the error on?

Comment: which line gives the error..? if info[1] = (dr["order_ID"].ToString());, then that means you need to start your index at 0 and the last one will be 19

Comment: what's in info[0]? arrays are zero-index based!

Comment: @DJKRAZE OP has array of size 20, so the last one will be `19` and not `5`

Comment: what does cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, db.mycon); look like can you paste in the full Method where this code is ..? also wrap your cmd.ExecuteReader() around a try catch where or how is dr declared ..?

Comment: what is MySqlCommand?................ And check(try to execute) the query in SQL

Comment: What happens if you execute this query in the MySql Workbench? Does it work?  Can you try creating a view and query that directly, and see if you get the same error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized the answer to this question is not easy to explain but it has something to do with the columns I am trying to recreate virtually through the command string. What I did and what solved the problem was to put the specific columns to retrieve in the `SELECT` query.

The working code:

```
 private void goDateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportList.Items.Clear();
            var db = new DBConnect();
            MySqlCommand cmd = null;
            MySqlDataReader dr = null;
            double totalsales = 0;
            try
            {
                if (db.OpenConnection() == true)
                {

                    string cmdstr = "SELECT DISTINCT ol.*, o.order_ID, o.order_date, o.order_status, m.*, mc.menu_cost " +
                                    "FROM  orderlist ol " +
                                        "INNER JOIN orderdb    o ON ol.order_ID = o.order_ID " +
                                        "INNER JOIN menudb     m ON ol.menu_ID  = m.menu_ID " +
                                        "INNER JOIN " +
                                            "(SELECT SUM(s.stock_pricePerPiece * r.recipe_quantity) AS menu_cost, m.menu_ID " +
                                                "FROM recipelist r " +
                                                    "INNER JOIN stocksdb s ON r.stock_ID = s.stock_ID " +
                                                    "INNER JOIN menudb m ON r.menu_ID= m.menu_ID " +
                                                "GROUP BY r.menu_ID " +
                                             ")" +
                                        "mc ON m.menu_ID = mc.menu_ID " +
                                    "WHERE o.order_date >= '" + fromDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " 00:00:00" + "' AND " +
                                        "o.order_date <= '" + toDate.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " 23:59:59" + "' AND " +
                                        "o.order_status = 'COMPLETED'";

                    if (menuCheckBox.Checked == true)
                    {
                        cmdstr = cmdstr + " AND m.menu_name = '" + menuBox.Text + "'";
                    }

                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, db.mycon);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    string[] info = new string[20];
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        info[1] = (dr["order_ID"].ToString());
                        info[2] = (dr["order_date"].ToString());
                        info[3] = (dr["menu_name"].ToString());
                        info[4] = (dr["order_quantity"].ToString());
                        info[5] = Convert.ToDouble(dr["menu_cost"].ToString()).ToString("#0.00");
                        info[6] = Convert.ToDouble(dr["menu_price"].ToString()).ToString("#0.00");
                        info[7] = ((Convert.ToDouble(dr["menu_price"].ToString()) * Convert.ToDouble(info[4])) - (Convert.ToDouble(dr["menu_cost"].ToString()) * Convert.ToDouble(info[4]))).ToString("#0.00");
                        this.reportList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4], info[5], info[6], info[7] }));

                        totalsales += Convert.ToDouble(info[7]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (dr != null)
                {
                    dr.Close();
                }
                db.CloseConnnection();
            }
            totalSalesTxtBox.Text = totalsales.ToString("#0.00");
            MessageBox.Show("SALES REPORT FINISHED!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Totally blowing away my previous answer based on your edit to the question noting which line is generating the error.

What happens if you do the following?  It might help diagnose your query syntax:

```
Console.WriteLine(cmdstr);
```

One thing I noticed is that you kinda need a space after the parenthesis here:

```
"GROUP BY stock_ID )"+
```

I don't *think* that will affect the query, but it might be worth trying.  Other than that, I'd suggest copying the query generated above and pasting it manually in your favorite SQL app and make sure it's syntactically correct.

Comment: I actually do have 6 columns

Comment: shouldn't that be Zero based in regards to adding and array ? I bet it's throwing an error at info[6] Indexes are Zero based in C#

Comment: Nah, I doubt this is the issue.  After he edited his post above, it looks like he's getting it on the ExecuteReader() line before it gets to adding the items into the ListView.